# Extra wing pieces (21+22) in Ferrari Daytona 42143. Did I miss a step or did Lego get it wrong?

Tags: technic, instructions

The Ferrari Daytona SP3 (42143) is supposed to have 10x 6319983 (small wing #22) and 11x 6316923 (small wing #21), both in black.

It says so on the part-list and they are in the box.

However I have 1 of each left-over after the build and I can't see where I missed an assembly step. (I may have missed something, but I can't figure out where, even after going over the 800+ pages of the instruction books again.)

As far as I can tell these pieces are located in the following spots on the model:

- Front lower spoiler: 2 of each
- Head light surrounds: 1 of each
- Front side spoilers: 1 of each
- Rear diffusor and valence: 4 of each
- engine top-cover: 1 of each
- And 1x #21 on the passenger side of the dashboard.

That all adds up as 9x #22 and 10x #21.

Either I missed something (can someone please tell me where in the model they were supposed to go) or Lego got their part-count wrong.

Which one is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The instructions had several errors. Here's an overview:
https://racingbrick.com/2022/06/lego-technic-42143-ferrari-daytona-sp3-instructions-errors-and-fixes/

One of them is the two panels you mentioned, they ideally should be added in step 1127, but you should be able to add them afterwards as well. There should be two red axles sticking at the back near the bottom where they attach.

Jordan Paxton (Engagement manager for the Lego group) was at the Parades De Coura lego fan weekend last weekend and explained during a Q&A session that the missing instructions happened because of something earlier in the build steps that needed to be updated and the update cascaded until this step and caused missing pages.

I've been told that rather interestingly the parts are also missing in the picture of the model on the box-art.

Comment: Aha... And I spotted those other manual errors myself as well. Already fixed. The mounting position is easily accessible on the complete model. And found another (minor) error: step 978, 979 have the angles wrong on fairing pieces #61 and #63 which looks really weird. Funny enough the corresponding steps on the other side of the vehicle don't have this mistake.

Comment: From the bottom of my heart: THANK YOU! I had the exact same problem.